# Align elements equally in VStack

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have two elements within a VStack where I would like to line up the boxes equally. I don't understand why they aren't lining up equally as they have the same paddings as one another.

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack{
                Text("Measurement: ")
                    .padding(.trailing, 20)
                Button(action: {
                    //button stuff
                   
                }){
                    Text("g")
                        .padding(.trailing, 25)
                        .padding(.leading, 25)
                         .border(.gray)
                         .foregroundColor(.black)
                        
                     
                }
                .padding(.leading, 30)
               
            }
           
            HStack {
                Text("Serving Size: ")
                    .padding(.trailing, 20)
                  
                Button(action: {
                    //button stuff
                    
                }){
                    Text(servingSizeSelection == ["1", "0"] ?
                         "1" :
                            servingSizeSelection.joined(separator: " "))
                   .padding(.trailing, 25)
                   .padding(.leading, 25)
                    .border(.gray)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
                .padding(.leading, 30)
            }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the reason the boxes are not lining up equally is that the text in the first HStack has a longer length than the text in the second HStack. This causes the buttons in the first HStack to be wider than the buttons in the second HStack, resulting in unequal spacing between the HStacks.

To fix this issue, you can add a fixed width to the Text views in both HStacks. For example, you can add .frame(width: 100) to both Text views like this:

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    HStack{
        Text("Measurement: ")
            .padding(.trailing, 20)
            .frame(width: 100) // Add a fixed width
        Button(action: {
            //button stuff

        }){
            Text("g")
                .padding(.trailing, 25)
                .padding(.leading, 25)
                .border(.gray)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
        }
        .padding(.leading, 30)

    }

    HStack {
        Text("Serving Size: ")
            .padding(.trailing, 20)
            .frame(width: 100) // Add a fixed width
        Button(action: {
            //button stuff

        }){
            Text(servingSizeSelection == ["1", "0"] ?
                 "1" :
                    servingSizeSelection.joined(separator: " "))
               .padding(.trailing, 25)
               .padding(.leading, 25)
                .border(.gray)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
        }
        .padding(.leading, 30)
    }
}
```